# A closed-form expression for a sequence of integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence of minimum values of the expression (depending on $\ell$):

\begin{equation*}
a_n=\arg\min \bigg\lbrace ((\ell+1)j-n)!\,(n-\ell j)!\quad \text{for}\; \,\bigg\lceil\frac{n}{\ell+1}\bigg\rceil\le j\le  \bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{\ell}\bigg\rfloor \bigg\rbrace
%  \min \big\lbrace (2j-n)!\,(n- j)!,\;  \mathrm{ceil}\,\frac{n}{2}\le j\le n \big\rbrace, 
.\end{equation*}

My questions is two fold:

Is there a closed-form expression for $(a_n)_{n\ge \ell}$ (for a fixed $\ell$), or a  way to characterize its entries?
Why?

Comment: So, $l$ is fixed in the definition of $a_n$, and only $j$ varies?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: For instance, for $\ell=1$, the sequence $(a_n)$ 
is:
\begin{align*}
  1,& 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 
11, 11,\\ 
12, &12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18,\\ 
19, &19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25, 25, 26, 26,\\
27, &27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 32, 32,...
\end{align*}
The patterns appears to be:
Two instances of every integer, except integers of the form $(n+1)^2-1$ which occurs only once in the sequence.

Comment: You've checked the OEIS already?

Comment: Yes, with no luck.

Comment: You mean *closeD formula*.

Comment: @dbir The values you give for $a_n$ above look more like values of $j$.  Did you mean "arg min" rather than "min"?  Are there possibly ties?  If so, how are you defining $j$ to be chosen?

Comment: Yes, I meant closed formula. I apologize.

Comment: It is "[closed-form expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)", not _closed formula_".

Comment: Also posted, without acknowledgement here or there, to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104367/a-closed-formula-for-a-sequence-of-integers

Comment: Erick is correct, I meant the argument of the minimum. Respect to the question about possible ties and what $j$ to choose, I do not know the answer, but any sequence that does the job is more than welcome.

Comment: I also posted (a similar) question in MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104367/a-closed-formula-for-a-sequence-of-integers

Comment: There's an echo in here.